# Using same CSS classes to many DIV

Tags: css, html

I am trying to use one CSS class to many DIV. Is it a good practice? or else are there any disadvantages of doing that. because in VS it says "another object already uses this ID", not an error message but a warning.

Comment: The error is about an id (as in `<div id="xyz" >`) and only one ID can belong to one tag. Using CSS classes can be used on many tags (as in `<div class="xyz'>`). A class is declared as `.xyz` in CSS and an ID as `#xyz`. These are two different things, don't mix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with styling multiple divs at the same time. This is actually expected and not many people do that. To style all divs;

```
body {Body Code Here;}
div {Div styling here;}
```

Styling all div's with one class;

```
body {Body Code Here;}
div.YourClass {Div Styling Here;}
```

Notice how there is no space between the div and selector(.) That specifies a class in any div where as `div .YourClass` will search in all divs for a class. IDs are different than Classes, you can have multiple Classes on the page but only 1 ID on the page. To fix that message, make sure you are using Class instead of ID and search the page for that ID and if it comes up twice or more, thats your problem. Again Classes are reusable and IDs are single-element selectors. Hope I helped!

Answer (score 2):

CSS classes are meant to be reused.  CSS IDs are meant to be used uniquely on a component. Are you sure you're using a css class?

Answer (score 1):

In css, class is meant to be reused, so it is ok. In case you don't know about id, id in css is meant to be used noce. But nowadays, I've seen few people use class all over place even  they just use it once. So, just keep your markup and styling clear, use class or id in your way if you work alone [ personal project ] and keep it persistence when working alone or in a team.

html

```
<div class="class1 class2">afd</div>
<div class="button class1">asffsdf</div>
```

css

```
.class1 { /* styling your class1 here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely fine to use the same class for many elements in CSS. Be careful not to do the same for the "id" attribute, which really should only be used for a single element as it is considered a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same CSS class for any number of elements, but ID must be unique for each and every element in the page

Answer (score 0):

ID is somewhat different from class. You can have multiple classes on page but ID should only be used once. Do follow best practices :)

i know... this information is not what exactly you want as answer but may be of some little help :)

example:

```
div.className { } //covers all div with a particular classname
```